Dynamics CRM Async Workflow result message
On CRM workflow instance there are two fields: Message and FriendlyMessage, but they are used by the system to show exceptions in case of process failure:

Everything is stored in AsyncOperationBase table but it's overwritten after process finishes.
Is there a way to put some data into those fields from activity code? I need to display some text statistics there reflecting execution result.
